# My Speaker is Muted After Boot

Tags: 22.04

I noticed that my Speaker is Recognized as Headphone in alsamixer. Every time I boot to my Ubuntu 22.04, I have to manually go to Alsamixer, Change MM to OO to unmute for headphone, and increase the volume to 100.

[image: screen shot]

How do I make alsamixer Headphone configuration so that it's automatically OO and has 100% volume after boot?

Comment: ggl alsarc file